# Partially matched shorter field takes precedence over completely matched larger field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two fields in my index on which I am querying. One is the **title** and another is **content**.
Content is a big field and contains entire content of an article.
Both fields have the same analyzer with min_gram as 3 and max_gram as 20.

Now the problem is when I search for a term and if the term completely matches the content field and partially matches the title field, title field takes precedence.

For example, I was searching for a term called **hacking**. 
Now there is a document which **contains hacking in its content field**. And there are **multiple docs whose title contains tracking** (which is not hacking by any means).

But when I do a query with hacking, all the tracking results come on top and hacking is in somewhere third or fourth page of results.  This is not what I expect. Hacking result should come on top. When I check the score the one with tracking as title gets 0.6 as score and one with hacking in the content gets  0.08 as the score, even though I have queried with Hacking.

My query looks like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query": "hacking", 
      "fields": ["title", "content"] 
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that shorter field always will be scored more. But that is not what is expected.

Please help how to fix this.
I tried it by boosting the larger field but the results are not satisfactory. 
Can't we make exact match get the first precedence no matter in which field it is present and then partial matches can come in the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "hacking",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "content"
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "75%",
            "type": "most_fields"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "hacking",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "content"
            ],
            "type": "phrase",
            "slop": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the `minimum_should_match` value is added to the first search component. Keep this in your query if you want to actually exclude results that don't have a certain amount of matching. You can also remove it without having any effect on the second part of the search.

The second part of the search is a phrase based query which will boost scores where the match is close to exact. The `slop` value determines how exact the match needs to be for the boost, `0` being an exact match.

Try using this search and tweaking some of the values defined here, you should get the results you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Two quick questions.
1. In the example, I gave only two fields title and content. But in our app there are multiple fields to be searched against. Around 10. Whether this will work even for 10 fields in fields array. Will it be performant?
2. Now in the fields array whether title still being the shorter field is boosted or I need to explicitly boost it?

Comment: You should be fine from a performance standpoint to include all 10 fields. ES will still boost matches against each field with its relevancy formula which will take each field length into account. This said, the best way to verify this is to test your index for relevancy and performance.